# open virtual box from live cd error

Tags: linux, virtualbox, live-cd

I am running Linux Mint in my laptop. I made some modifications and I couldn't login in linux enviroment. I boot in live cd (Linux Mint) and I recover my important files from desktop.

I had some important files in virtual machine. I install virtual box in live cd and when I  double click in file.vbox it appears the message:

> Failed to open virtual machine located in /media/mint/home/xxx/VirtualBox VMs/file2/file.vbox.
> A differencing image of snapshot {xxxxxxxxxxxxxx} could not be found. Could not find an open hard disk with UUID {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}.

I try also to "create new virtual machine" and then choose "use an existing virtual hard drive" and choose the snapshot but it pop up another message:

> Failed to open the hard disk file /media/mint/home/xxx/VirtualBox VMs/file2/file.vbox.
>
> Parent medium with UUID {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx} of the medium '/media/mint/home/xxx/VirtualBox VMs/file2/file.vbox./Snapshots/{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}.vdi' is not found in the media registry ('/home/mint/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml').
>
> Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
> Component: Medium
> Interface: IMedium {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
> Callee: IVirtualBox {xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
> Callee RC: VBOX_E_OBJECT_NOT_FOUND (xxxxxxxxxxx)

Can anyone help me to recover my files from virtual box boot in live cd?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This question is off-topic here, try superuser.com or other site where questions related to linux administration are allowed.

Answer (score 7):

Hy i got a same error on a different Issue.

How i fixed it:

1. **backup your your VirtualMachine.vbox file.**
2. open your yourVirtualMachine.vbox file with an editor such as Notepad++
3. search through the vbox file for your missing UUID e.g. *36bbf5bd-3a5e-48ab-80d6-6a2952788fdc*
4. you should find a Section with Tags like this:
5. delete the whole section beginning by `<AttachedDevice>` and ending by  `</AttachedDevice>` (if you have a backup of your vbox file)
6. save your edited file
7. start your VirtualBox; you should be able to import your virtual machine with this vbox file
8. edit your imported VM
9. open the tab "storage" in edit window
   9.1) add a new hard disk (your existing VM file e.g. vdi, vmdk) to IDE- or SATA-Controller

Hopefully, you should be able to start your VM

Comment: This question may be off topic for stackoverflow, but I'm sure glad I found the answer @stephanfriedrich posted! I first found this question on Superuser, but it had no answers there. I had the same VBox error message and this solution worked  perfectly - it really saved my bacon today and I'm grateful, so +1 for this answer to an "off-topic" question!

Comment: @knutsondc, thx i answered the Superuser Question too and iam glad to help you ;).

Comment: @3456 maybe its time to delete these post.